# Assembly x86 "PSHUFB 128bit" implementation in another language

Tags: python, algorithm, assembly, x86, hex

I was reversing some application and i faced this opcode:

```
PSHUFB XMM2, XMMWORD_ADDRESS
```

and i tried implementing the algorithm of this function in python with no success!
The reference of how this opcode should work is here:
http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFB.html

Here is a code snippet:

```
PSHUFB (with 128 bit operands)

    for i = 0 to 15 {
         if (SRC[(i * 8)+7] = 1 ) then
              DEST[(i*8)+7..(i*8)+0] ← 0;
          else
              index[3..0] ← SRC[(i*8)+3 .. (i*8)+0]; DEST[(i*8)+7..(i*8)+0] ← DEST[(index*8+7)..(index*8+0)];
         endif
    }
DEST[VLMAX-1:128] ← 0
```

im trying to implement the 128 version of this opcode with no success.
Here are the values before and after the function

***Before***

```
WINDBG>r xmm2
xmm2=           0 3.78351e-044 6.09194e+027 6.09194e+027
```

***After***

```
WINDBG>r xmm2
xmm2=9.68577e-042            0 4.92279e-029 4.92279e-029
```

in python you can use 'struct' to change those from float numbers to Hex:

```
hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', f))[0])
```

So i can sort of say those are the hex values of *XMM2* before and after the *PSHUFB* opcode:

***Before***

```
xmm2 = 0 0x0000001b 0x6d9d7914 0x6d9d7914
```

***After***

```
xmm2 = 00001b00 00000000 10799d78 10799d78
```

And most importantly, i almost forgot.. the value of ***XMMWORD_ADDRESS*** is:

> 03 02 01 00 07 06 05 04 0D 0C 0B 0A 09 08 80 80
>
> xmmword 808008090A0B0C0D0405060700010203h

Implementation in Python could be highly appreciated.
Implementation in C could work as well

or maybe some explanation of how the hell it works!
Because i couldnt understand the intel reference

This is the code algorithm i have so far

```
x = ['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '1b', '6d', '9d', '79', '14', '6d', '9d', '79', '14']
s = ['03', '02', '01', '00', '07', '06', '05', '04', '0D', '0C', '0B', '0A', '09', '08', '80', '80']
new = []
for i in range(16):
    if 0x80 == int(s[i], 16) & 0x80:
        print "MSB", s[i]
        new.append(0)
    else:
        print "NOT MSB", s[i]
        new.append( x[int(s[i], 16) & 15] )
       
print x
print new
```

Where x is the xmm0, and s is the SRC.

the output i get is:

> ['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '1b', '6d', '9d', '79',
> '14', '6d', '9d', '79', '14']
>
> ['00', '00', '00', '00', '1b', '00', '00', '00', '9d', '6d', '14',
> '79', '9d', '6d', '00', '00']

where i should get

> ['00', '00', '1b', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '10', '79', '9d',
> '78', '10', '79', '9d', '78']

Something else i have noticed right now, in the 'output' i get the hexadecimal number 0x78
Where could it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works like 16 parallel table lookups, with special handling for indexes that have their top bit set. So for example, it could look like this: (not tested, not Python)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    new_dest[i] = (src[i] & 0x80) ? 0 : dest[src[i] & 15];
dest = new_dest;
```

The `new_dest` there is significant, because it's really 16 *parallel assignments*, ie read-before-write, the second lookup is not affected by what happened in to the first byte and so on. Intel's code snippet leaves that implicit (or is wrong, depending on how you look at it).

Comment: in your solution
src - should be list of bytes? (0x10, 0x22, 0x33, ...)

so im checking the 'Most Significant Bit - MSB - 0x80' on every '1 BYTE'?

'MSB' On so put 0, else put the number of current src value? Wow that something else.

Gonna try implementing this right now lets see if i get it right

Comment: Not quite there yet.. i have added the current implementation and outputs to my question

Comment: @RE-Beginner probably the usual little-endian problem, I'll look at it more closely after class